# 2 loggers created.How are they associated?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I am trying to use java.utils.logging.. I have these two files MyLogger and UseLogger.MyLogger sets the logger up with a file handler ..
UseLogger writes into the log.
Here are the two files..

```
package UtilsLogging;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.io.IOException;

/* Setting the logger up.
 * Create logger,define its level.
 * Create a file handler,mention the formatter,add handler to the logger
 */

public class MyLogger {

    static private SimpleFormatter sf;
    static private FileHandler txtLogFile;

    public static void setup() throws IOException{
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        sf = new SimpleFormatter();

        txtLogFile = new FileHandler("mytxtlog.txt");
        txtLogFile.setFormatter(sf);
        logger.addHandler(txtLogFile);
    }

}
```

and

```
package UtilsLogging;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class UseLogger {

    private static final Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(MyLogger.class.getName());

    public void writeToLog(){
    lgr.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
    lgr.info("info1");

    lgr.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    lgr.severe("severe2");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        UseLogger ul = new UseLogger();
        try{
            MyLogger.setup();
        }
        catch(IOException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

        ul.writeToLog();
    }
}
```

What i donot understand is this..After calling MyLogger.setup(), i say ul.writeToLog() which is writing to the file mytxtlog.txt. Am i not creating two different loggers in the two files..How is the logger in UseLogger able t associate itself to the logger setup done in MyLogger.. Does Logger.GetLogger("") have to do something with my questions?
I tried reading on this but my question remains unanswered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below call gives you the root logger.

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");

And the root logger is parent of every logger. So if you have not set the logging level or handler for a particular logger it will inherit it from the parent logger recursively (if set) or from the root logger (by default).

Comment: YEs.thats right..Found an interesting article on logger hierarchy later http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/logger-hierarchy.html